# Format generated buttons with css

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to apply a css class (push_button) to rendered buttons.

```
     buttons = if is_rc?
    ['Approve', 'Submit', 'Incomplete', 'Reject']
  elsif !@product.my_product?
    ['Save']
  elsif @product.container_type || !@product.uses_ingredients.empty?
    ['Submit for certification']
  else
    ['Continue to formula']
  end
  buttons.map {|b| submit_tag(b), (:class => "push_button") }.join(' ') %>
```

This results in an error.  Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: can you try it this way? `buttons.map { |b| submit_tag(b, class: "push_button" }.join(' ')`

Comment: It would help if you could share the error

Comment: I followed that and got this error:
syntax error, unexpected ':'\n....map {|b| submit_tag(b, class: \"push_button\" }.join(' ') ).t...\n ^"